# How to access the entity value in Luis

Tags: python, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I want to print the value of the entity that is already defined in the Luis portal, I already printed the TopIntent but I need to access the entity and print the value of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/client-libraries-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-python):

You can get entity and subentities, for example:

```
modelObject = client.model.get_entity(app_id, versionId, modelId)
toppingQuantityId = get_grandchild_id(modelObject, "Toppings", "Quantity")
pizzaQuantityId = get_grandchild_id(modelObject, "Pizza", "Quantity")
```

If you want to get the prediction from the runtime, for example:

```
# Production == slot name
predictionRequest = { "query" : "I want two small pepperoni pizzas with more salsa" }

predictionResponse = clientRuntime.prediction.get_slot_prediction(app_id, "Production", predictionRequest)
print("Top intent: {}".format(predictionResponse.prediction.top_intent))
print("Sentiment: {}".format (predictionResponse.prediction.sentiment))
print("Intents: ")

for intent in predictionResponse.prediction.intents:
    print("\t{}".format (json.dumps (intent)))
print("Entities: {}".format (predictionResponse.prediction.entities))
```

You can refer to [How to extract entity from Microsoft LUIS using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446315/how-to-extract-entity-from-microsoft-luis-using-python)